# Python for loop and lists

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension

I have the following in code; which I forgot where I got it or what's it called (I'm new to Python):

```
deck = [Card(x, y) for x in cards for y in suits]
```

From the above code, I am trying to create multiple decks into a list, so that the user inputs the number of decks. I have been trying to do it like this:

```
decks = 2
i = 0
while i < decks:
    deck = [Card(x, y) for x in cards for y in suits]
    i += 1
```

But that just overwrites the current deck variable. I also tried:

```
decks = 2
deck = []
i = 0
while i < decks:
    deck.append(Card(x, y) for x in cards for y in suits)
    i += 1
```

But I only get `<generator object <genexpr> at 0x04562C30>` and `<generator object <genexpr> at 0x04562BF0>` as output when I print the contents of the deck. How exactly do I achieve what I want and how do the two for loops work in the creation of the list?

I tried the following to iterate over the members of the list; doesn't work:

```
for x in deck:
    for j in x:
        print(str(deck[x][j]))
```

Comment: That is called list comprehension.

Comment: `deck.append([...])`?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try this:

```
deck.append([Card(x, y) for x in cards for y in suits])
```

This will be a list of lists. but I think all of the items will be the same in that list.

EDIT:

```
for x in deck:
    for j in x:
        print(j) # or do what you want, j is that inner element
```

Comment: How do I iterate over the members of the inner lists? Do I need two loops for that?

Comment: Yes, you need two loop for accessing all of them but individually you can `deck[i][j]`. i and j will be the Integer indexes.

Comment: You can iterate over them and flat the like this: `[member for l in deck for member in l]`

Comment: Could you edit the answer to include how to iterate over the members please. I have edited my question what I tried and it doesn't work.

Comment: sure,just `print(j)` instead of `str(deck[x][j])`

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what happens when all of the elements of one inner list are popped? Does it still see the main list having two lists; one empty, one full?

Comment: It will be like this: `[ [] , [e1,e2,...]]`

Answer (score 2):

You should change this,

```
deck.append(Card(x, y) for x in cards for y in suits)
```

into this:

```
deck.append([Card(x, y) for x in cards for y in suits])
```

Instead of appending a generator object each iteration of the list comprehension, which is what the first line does, the second line stores the data in a list and *then* appends it.

Answer (score 1):

Just adding a comprehension version for the sake of completion.

```
decks = 2

deck = [[(x,y) for x in cards for y in suits] for i in range(decks)]
```

Comment: Would this create a single list or two lists in a list?

Comment: 2 Lists in a list.